# Proof that $\zeta (-n)=(-1)^n\frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1}$ for $n\ge 0$

Tags: riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

I'd like to prove that 
$$\zeta (-n)=(-1)^n\dfrac{B_{n+1}}{n+1}\quad n\ge 0.$$
The only approach I found uses
$$\zeta (-n)=\dfrac{in!}{2\pi}\displaystyle\oint_C \dfrac{(-t)^{-n-1}}{e^t-1} \, dt.$$
Can the identity for $\zeta (-n)$ be proved by any other means (not by contour integration)? At least links to some sources would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use the functional equation.  Dr. Jerry Shurman sketches this in [Zeta at Negative Odd Integers, a la Euler](https://people.reed.edu/%7Ejerry/311/euler.pdf).  First he shows, for even $k \geq 2$,
$$  \zeta(1-k) = \frac{2 \Gamma(k)}{(2 \pi \mathrm{i})^k} \zeta(k)  $$
This ties values of $\zeta$ at negative odd integers to reflected values at positive even integers.

Are you comfortable with how the Bernoulli numbers show up for zeta evaluated at positive even integers?

Comment: Yes, I'm comfortable with that. Thanks, this helped me.